# Updated upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini but still cant upload large files

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-22.04

I am using a Laravel based app on Ubuntu 22.04, Nginx, `php8.2-fpm`. I have deployed the same app on 2 other servers but they use Ubuntu 20.04 and `php8.1-fpm`.

In each case I updated the `php.ini` of both the cli and the fpm.
When I run `cat php.ini | grep upload_max_filesize` it shows the values I updated.
I have restarted php, nginx and the server several times.

On the old servers large file uploads are no problem.
However on the new server I can not upload files larger than `2M`.

Does anyone know of any other settings I need to be aware of?
I'm, just completely baffled right now.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I sussed it out. I must have known it in the past but forgotten. The first server had `client_max_body_size 500M;` in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. Once I updated this on the new server everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to increase [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

`post_max_size` sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: thank you my friend, I really appreciate you taking the time to leave an answer. Actually, I should have mentioned, I already had that covered.